# How design a Deterministic finite automata which accept string starting with 101 and how to draw transition table for it if there is a dead state

Tags: finite-automata, computation-models

I’m trying to design a DFA
which accept string starting with 101 if the string start with 0 then it goes to dead state.Is my design is correct or wrong? And I don’t know how to draw transition table if the DFA has dead state.

[image]

Comment: The dfa is generally correct. You could add a self-loop to q3 so that the automaton stays in q3 if it receives more 1s and 0s. the table has 3 columns: state, 0, 1. State contains all states. In the column 1 you just write to what the state in the state column switches if it receives a 1. Same thing for the 0 column.

Comment: Ok the I should mention dead state in transition table?

Comment: Yes. Its a state like all the other states. Also the dead state should have a self loop since it you stay in dead state even if you receive a 1 or 0 as input.

Comment: Ok thanks for your response